# Embed a DIV inside a PDF

Tags: html, jquery, css, pdf

I embed a pdf through iframe. Now I want to insert a DIV element to that pdf.
I tried below way. But it doesn't give me the correct solution. It's embedded out of the pdf page. I want to embed div inside the pdf page. Is there any way to do that?

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', myInit, false);
    function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
    function myInit()
    {
      var moveMe = byId('moveMe');
      var coverMe = byId('coverMe');

      var coverPosX,coverPosY;
      var coverWidth, coverHeight;

      var movePosX, movePosY;
      var moveWidth, moveHeight;

      coverPosX = coverMe.clientLeft;
      coverPosY = coverMe.clientTop;
      coverWidth = coverMe.clientWidth;
      coverHeight = coverMe.clientHeight;

      moveWidth = moveMe.clientWidth;
      moveHeight = moveMe.clientHeight;

      movePosX = (coverWidth - moveWidth) / 2;
      movePosY = (coverHeight - moveHeight) / 2;

      var tgt = moveMe;
      tgt.style.left = movePosX + 'px';
      tgt.style.top = movePosY + 'px';

    }
  </script>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .above
    {
      position: absolute;
      left:100px;
      display: inline-block;
      color: red;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 24px;
      border: solid 4px red;
      background-color: rgba(51,51,51,0.3);
      border-radius: 16px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<embed id='coverMe' src='my.pdf' width="100%" height="1300px;" name="plugin"  type="application/pdf">
<div class='above' id='moveMe'>Anytext</div>
<script src="../js/view-pdf-controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: how it's going on if u removed the position: absolute; from .above class CSS style ?

Comment: It doesn't appear

Comment: No. HTML and CSS can be converted to PDF with some exceptions, but you cannot embed HTML and CSS inside a PDF